How is the integral of a simple function well-defined in Folland?
I am reading Folland's real analysis text, section 2.2 on integration of nonnegative functions. I am stuck at the definition of the integral of a simple function and how to show it is well-defined. There are related questions/answers to mine which I've included at the end together with a short comment.
Folland defines a simple function $f$ as a finite linear combination of characteristic functions. In its (unique) standard representation, a simple function has a distinct range $\{z_1,\ldots,z_n\},z_i\neq z_j,$ and the disjoint sets of the characteristic functions are simply $E_k=f^{-1}(\{z_k\})$.
Then, given $f=\sum_1^n z_j\chi_{E_j}$ in its standard representation, the integral of $f$ with respect to $\mu$ is $$\int f\,d\mu=\sum_1^n z_j\mu(E_j).$$This definition is followed by a proposition on basic properties of the integral of a simple function, among them linearity.
Now, comparing with another text (Stein and Shakarchi's real analysis text), they use the very same definitions (except that Folland allows one of the coefficients $z_i$ to be $0$). In their Proposition 1.1 on page 50, they first prove that the integral of a simple function is well-defined (i.e. independent of any representation) and then linearity. And proving linearity follows easily from the fact that it is independent of representation.
My question is; since Folland does not mention or comment on independence of representation, is it possible to deduce this from the linearity of the integral? In other words, doing the opposite of what Stein and Shakarchi are doing? I have not been able to understand this for days now and would be grateful for any clarification.
Related questions/answers:

question 1 (asking why we need to prove independence of representation given the definition in Folland's text, but not really addressing how we can prove it given the definitions in Folland's text)
answer 2 (the first part mentions linearity, yet I don't see how independence of representation follows from it)


I've lost track of who the various "they" and "their" pronouns refer to. Perhaps hit the edit button and express more clearly which book is referred to by each pronoun.

Folland first defines integrals of simple functions in standard representation, then defines integrals of non-negative measurable $f$ (and he remarks this coincides with the original definition when $f$ is simple), and makes a small remark on homogeneity ($\int cf=c\int f$ for all $c\in [0,\infty)$), then proves $\sigma$-additivity, $\int\sum_nf_n=\sum_n\int f_n$.
With these facts in mind, suppose $f$ is a non-negative simple function, with standard representation $\sum_{i=1}^nz_i\chi_{E_i}$ and let’s say it also equals $\sum_{j=1}^mc_j\chi_{F_j}$. Then,
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^nz_i\mu(E_i)&=\int_X f\,d\mu\tag{definition}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^mc_j\int_X \chi_{F_j}\,d\mu\tag{non-negative linearity}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^mc_j\mu(F_j),
\end{align}
where the final equal sign is because the function $\chi_{F_j}$ is already its standard representation.

More generally, suppose

$\mathcal{F}$ is a set equipped with operations of addition and scalar multiplication by non-negative numbers, such that it is closed under countably infinite non-negative linear combinations
$\mathcal{F}_0\subset\mathcal{F}$ a ‘spanning set’ (with respect to countably infinite non-negative linear combinations)
$I_0:\mathcal{F}_0\to[0,\infty]$ a given map.

Then, there is at most one map $I:\mathcal{F}\to [0,\infty]$ which is linear (with respect to non-negative countably-infinite linear combinations) and $I|_{\mathcal{F}_0}=I_0$. The reason is that given $f\in \mathcal{F}$, we can express it as $f=\sum c_nf_n$ for some $c_n\in [0,\infty)$ and $f_n\in\mathcal{F}_0$. So,
\begin{align}
I(f)=\sum c_n I(f_n)=\sum c_n I_0(f_n),
\end{align}
which proves that $I$ depends only on $I_0$. (Another way of saying this is that if $J$ is another such map, then $J(f)=\sum c_nI_0(f_n)$ as well).
For the purposes of integration, we take $\mathcal{F}$ to be the space of non-negative measurable functions, $\mathcal{F}_0$ the indicators of measurable sets (and it’s pretty straight forward to show it ‘spans’ $\mathcal{F}$), and define $I_0(\chi_E):=\mu(E)$. Then, there is at most one $I$ by the above abstract reasoning. Concrete reasoning actually shows an $I$ exists. Thus, we have existence and uniqueness, and this is the Lebesgue integral $I=\int_X(\cdot)\,d\mu$ of non-negative measurable functions.
